# Как оптимизировать сортировку списка ol?

Tags: css

У меня есть список ol. С помощью свойств css он изменяет порядок отображения списка li. Но есть проблема, скролл при умолчании в самом низу, как сделать так, чтобы он был в самом вверху при загрузке страницы??? [Список](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvoOm.png)[image: код css]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чтобы скролл (указан на фото стрелочкой) был в самом вверху по дефолту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать scrollIntoView() для последнего элемента в списке.

```js
lastli = document.querySelector('ol li:last-child');
lastli.scrollIntoView();
```

```css
ol {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
  <li>testtesttest</li>
</ol>
```